Dependency conflict react native when installing react-native-web
I have been developing the apps and testing the result using npm start -> scan the barcode on my phone. Now, I tried to open it via website, and it gives me a depedency conflict error
I tried to run this in order to be able to run via web
npm install react-native-web

and this is the output from terminal

Here is my package.json
{
  "name": "rpsgame",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.24.0",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "^4.5.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^20.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^20.3.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.18",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.11.0",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.4.1",
    "expo": "~51.0.24",
    "expo-splash-screen": "^0.27.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "firebase": "^10.12.5",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.10.8",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.33.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}

what should I do?

npm install react-native-web --force.        use  this command

is okay to use force? I read somewhere else it is not that recommended to use it @MahammadMomin
